# Changes to my dockerfile are not reflected when running `docker build`

Tags: docker

Docker beginner here. I'm trying to build a docker image by invoking `docker build -t my_image .` and making changes to the dockerfile on lines that fail. I'm currently running into a problem on this line:

`RUN apt-get install -qy locales`

Which was corrected after previously being:

`RUN apt-get install -q locales` (I forgot the `-y` which assumes 'yes' inputs.)

But, when I run the build command again, the change to `-qy` is seemingly not reflected:

```
 ---> Running in bc68a3eec929
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-l10n
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-l10n locales
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4907 kB of archives.
After this operation, 20.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -q locales' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What I've tried:

- Removing any recently stopped containers
- Removing any recently built images (which were all failed)
- Using `docker build --no-cache -t my_image .`

Note that I do not use VOLUME in the dockerfile. I saw some users had problems with this, but it's not my issue.

In short, why are changes to my dockerfile not recognized during the build command?

Comment: What's the base image you are using?

Comment: @AnuradhaFernando debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have mentioned, I think the first failure is not due to `-qy`, it must be due to not updating the repos before running the `apt-get` commands.

Can you try this and see?

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qy locales
```

Comment: I find it strange that this works, when I already have `RUN apt-get update` in the file two lines above. Any idea why?

Comment: @strangelycutlemon not specifically, maybe because you are creating 2 different layers? or perhaps, test without using --no-cache during the docker image build.