# I made a change to my Dockerfile, but my "docker build" isn't reflecting the change

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, dockerfile

I'm learning how to use docker, this docker image is being built with a Spring Boot REST API that was running fully local.

My first docker image was as below

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src

RUN ./mvnw install -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.helloyou.demo.DemoApplication"]
```

When I first run the command `docker build -t myapp .` I got this result

```
jamal@DESKTOP-64JJ5P8:~/dev/hello-you-endpoint$ docker build -t fer2ap/app .
[+] Building 7.5s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                2.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                   3.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk                                                     1.9s
 => [stage-1 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk@sha256:76acd2ab267cb71abeab875af97d91fb483d81bc4e372d1dd28ba  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                   1.4s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/5] RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 4/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/META-INF /app/META-INF                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 5/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes /app                                                 0.0s
------
 > [stage-1 3/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib:
------
------
 > [stage-1 4/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/META-INF /app/META-INF:
------
------
 > [stage-1 5/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes /app:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes" not found: not found
```

At first I thought this was an error on the `WORKDIR` and `ARG DEPENDENCY`. So I made a change to it, in order to match my project's absolute path `~/dev/hello-you-endpoint`. The Dockerfile after the change was like this

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk as build
WORKDIR dev/hello-you-endpoint
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw install
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
VOLUME /tmp
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=dev/hello-you-endpoint/target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.helloyou.demo.DemoApplication"]
```

When I run the `docker build -t myapp .` I got the same output `failed to compute cache key: "/workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib" not found: not found`.

```
jamal@DESKTOP-64JJ5P8:~/dev/hello-you-endpoint$ docker build -t fer2ap/app .
[+] Building 8.6s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                3.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                   2.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk                                                     3.2s
 => [auth] library/amazoncorretto:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                   1.4s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk@sha256:76acd2ab267cb71abeab875af97d91fb483d81bc4e372d1dd28ba  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/5] RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 4/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/META-INF /app/META-INF                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 5/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes /app                                                 0.0s
------
 > [stage-1 3/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib:
------
------
 > [stage-1 4/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/META-INF /app/META-INF:
------
------
 > [stage-1 5/5] COPY /workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes /app:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib" not found: not found
```

I thought receiving the same error was weird, so I kept trying to find the problem. I deleted all the content inside my Dockerfile and I got the same error `failed to compute cache key: "/workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes" not found: not found`.

Before writing this question, I found some similar cases ( [Changes to my dockerfile are not reflected when running `docker build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737482/changes-to-my-dockerfile-are-not-reflected-when-running-docker-build) ) but none of their solutions work for me. I did some research and I learned a little bit about docker cache, but `docker build --no-cache -t myapp .` didn't work also.

Before trying to build the image with multi-layer support, I did the first spring boot with docker tutorial ( https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/ ). By the end of the Getting started tutorial, I had the following Dockerfile. I tried to build my image with it but it is also not working now and when using this Dockerfile I get the same error as above `failed to compute cache key: "/workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib" not found: not found`.

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.helloyou.demo.DemoApplication"]
```

File structure: My Dockerfile, mvnw, pom.xml and the source folder for my app are at /home/jamal/dev/hello-you-endpoint/

Comment: You have to copy things from the build image. `${DEPENDENCY}` is just a ARG in your final image and has nothing to do with `target/dependency` from the build.

Comment: @QuangNguyen but why does the command `docker build ...` still run even if I remove all its content?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your can construct your dockerfile as this example

```
FROM golang AS build-stage
RUN go get -u github.com/LK4D4/vndr

FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /go/bin/vndr /
```

Comment: I added the "AS build-stage" and "AS export-stage", removed the WORKDIR and added the "--from=build-stage" to the COPY commands. But I got the same error `failed to compute cache key: "/workspace/app/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib" not found: not found`.

Comment: During the night I understood what you want to say. I changed the Dockerfile here and it's working. I still believe there was another bug on my way other than writing correctly the Dockerfile